# Do I need to double check flows in UT?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a class `A`  with a dependency `B`.

I wrote a UT to `B::foo(String s1, String s2)`. Say I test a flow of `B::foo("a", "a")`

Assuming `A::foo(..)` calls `B::foo(..)`

Do I have to write a UT of `A::("a", "a")` ?

I would inject B::foo mock and check it was called once and also the result from A is as expected given a mocked result from B.

Would you avoid mock in such situation?

Would you avoid the whole flow as it's already checked in `B` UT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests serve as an additional line of defense against software bugs. Making bug in production code is likely, making same bug in both production code *and* unit test is a lot less likely. This is one of the reasons you write unit tests - to gain one more guarantee your software works as intended.

> I would inject B::foo mock and check it was called once and also the result from A is as expected given a mocked result from B.

You need to ask yourself how much you gain by doing so. If `A` is simple wrapper over `B`

- How valuable would such `A` tests be?
- How hard would a bug in `A` code be to detect?
- And how easy to make?
- And how hard to fix?

Every unit test is a decision to be made. There is no *"Yes, write tests for this class"* guideline nor rule. You need to determine whether your time can be spend on writing unit tests for wrapper class or whether it would be better to invest it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`B::foo` is unit tested, so the best course of action is to *assume it is perfect*. If you have reason to doubt that `B::foo` is perfect, add tests in `BTest` until you're comfortable with it, then assume that it is perfect.

At that point, writing a unit test of `A::foo` is probably redundant, unless you're asserting that it accurately returns (some permutation of) `B::foo`. As [jimmy_keen said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127124/1426891), this may mean that your test for `A` is trivial. Remember that unit tests are designed to cover things likely to break, so if all you have is a wrapper, you probably don't need thorough testing.

(Caveat: If `B` is not under your control, and you can't be confident of its perfection, by all means add `B` tests wherever in  you can—including a separate test class, or in `ATest`. That's a separate abstraction-breaking case, though.)